# Autopopulate a node with the content of a menu

Tags: views, routes

supose i have a site with three nodes of basic page type called "element 1", "element 2" and "element 3". I want to create a menu with the following structure:
-elements
--element 1
--element 2
--element 3
Is there any way to generate a view for the "elements" node containing the children nodes from the menu, a module to do this automatically or somthing like that.
Sorry if that may be an obvious question, but im relatively new in drupal, also pardon my english

Comment: it should be able to do be done in Views.  Have you tried anything yet? Drupal Answers isn't a place to find or ask for tutorials - there are plenty of those around with a simple web search

Comment: I haven´t tried anything because i have no clue on what to do, and yes, i did a google search and still don´t know how it´s done.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new View, Block, Content -> 'Basic Page', fields

once the main Views UI opens you can modify as desired - by default, this will create a view of Titles that act as links in a block you can place wherever you like. You can remove the Title (title) by clicking on the Title Field, and un-click 'Create a label'